# getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1

Tags: android, admob, addsubview

I am testing my application in device it is showing the error in debug logcat what is this error and how to solve this?

The error is

```
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
```

my xml code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_light"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

     >
      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

my code to display the ads is

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in manifest file I am adding.the code is working fine but the ads are not displaying I am testing it on my device

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Answer (score 27):

Try to use Ad unit ID.

You may mistakenly use the APP ID or PUBLISHER ID.. (Like my mistake)

Sample Ad Unit ID (it contains xxxxx/xxxxx)

**ca-app-pub-9390048287444061/3221111032**   - correct one

Sample App ID (it contains xxxxx~xxxxx)

**ca-app-pub-9390048287444061~1222077830**  - wrong one

Comment: I cant imagine how stupid I was to use App ID instead of Ad Unit ID and searching every other solution why ads were not being shown. Thanks Man

Answer (score 2):

the issue is solved by adding the ad-Unit Id Other than publisher id and adding the test device id through AdRequest

Answer (score 1):

as you say,
you have done all attempt write all code perfectly in **manifest** as well as **build.gradle** file.
this same problem was to me.

so after that i have resolved this problem by *correcting* my **ad-mob unit id** and also 
it was written in *uppercase*.so i modify it to *lowercase* and works perfectly.

This works for me.Hope this help others too!!.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I believe Error Code 1 is due to many different reasons, but mine was wrong adSize. I set up for NativeAdExpress, but was giving wrong dimensions in XML, MEDIUM_RECTANGLE worked for my NativeAdExpress view.

Answer (score -3):

try adding below code to you gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
```

Comment: You didn't explained the line that you have added and it is not related answer in anyway.