# Banner Ads in between recyclerview android

Tags: android, admob

In my app i am having a recyclerview adapter so i want to show banner ads in between the items, i applied the following code in my adapter class, but its showing an error

> Failed to load ad, error code 1

i checked that the appid is correct

```
public RecyclerViewAdapterMore.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerViewAdapterMore.ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            AdView adView = new AdView(context);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.app_id));

            float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
            adView.setLayoutParams(params);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            viewHolder = new RecyclerViewAdapterMore.ViewHolder(adView);
        }
        else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new RecyclerViewAdapterMore.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Comment: Please refer [this link (It might help)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384445/getting-an-ad-response-errorcode-1/33385216?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Did you just created ad unit ?

Comment: @Lucifer Ya created ad unit, and its working too.

Comment: good, is your Test Unit ID working ok ?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit  thnx bor, it helped, in place of adunitid i was placing the appid, now changed, but now getting another problem, its showing this message "Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x49 dp, but only has 116x17 dp", so ads not serving, any idea to resolve this

Comment: @RanaPratap It is related to your XML as it is not getting enough room to display the add. Please share your XML code.

Comment: @VirRajpurohit  i am displaying the ad directly using programming code only not in xml page, the xml page is having a recyclerview and a card view only

Comment: The card views are in square grids, so i wanted to put banner ads after 6 cards i.e., after 2 rows each, each row is having 3 cards so after every 6 cards i wanted to display banner ads

Comment: @RanaPratap Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862315/admob-error-not-enough-space-to-show-ad-needs-320x50-dp-but-only-has-309x0-dp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)